# Bash provide comma-separated list in multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I have a bash script that is suppose to run another program called file-selector.

```
#!/bin/bash
...

./file-selector -exclude="a/b/c/d/e/f1,a/b/c/d/e/f2,a/b/c/d/e/f3,a/b/c/d/e/f4,a/b/c/d/e/f5,a/b/c/d/e/f6"

...
```

I want to change the file-selector line into something like this:

```
./file-selector -exclude="a/b/c/d/e/f1,\
                          a/b/c/d/e/f2,\
                          a/b/c/d/e/f3,\
                          a/b/c/d/e/f4,\
                          a/b/c/d/e/f5,\
                          a/b/c/d/e/f6"
```

The `-exclude` option is expecting a comma-separated list of paths.

But the file-selector program is exiting with an error probably because of all the white spaces and line feeds it encounters.

Is there a better way to write this expression to be equivalent to the 1-liner ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the values without separators in an array. Use the fact that `"${array[*]}"` expands to a single word that contains all the members of the array concatenated, with the first character of `$IFS` in between.

For what you want to do, you need `IFS=,`.

The altered `IFS` may affect commands later in the script, including the one that gets the argument in question (`./file-selector` in your case). To avoid this, use the altered IFS only to rewrite the array to a non-array variable; next restore the old value of `IFS` and only then run actual commands.

Saving and restoring `IFS` has its quirk: empty is not equivalent to unset (although `"$IFS"` expands to an empty string in both cases). Still Bash (at least Bash 5.2.15 I tested) sets `IFS` to <space><tab><newline> when it starts interpreting a script, so the initial `IFS` in your script is certainly neither empty nor unset. This means it's safe to store and restore it. Hardcoded `IFS=$' \t\n'` to restore the default value would also work.

Proof of concept:

```
#!/bin/bash
oldIFS="$IFS"
excludes=(
            a/b/c/d/e/f1
            a/b/c/d/e/f2
            a/b/c/d/e/f3
            a/b/c/d/e/f4
            a/b/c/d/e/f5
            a/b/c/d/e/f6
         )
IFS=,
exc="${excludes[*]}"
IFS="$oldIFS"
printf '<%s>\n' ./file-selector -exclude="$exc"
```

The output is:

```
<./file-selector>
<-exclude=a/b/c/d/e/f1,a/b/c/d/e/f2,a/b/c/d/e/f3,a/b/c/d/e/f4,a/b/c/d/e/f5,a/b/c/d/e/f6>
```

which means the argument was exactly as you wanted.

The whole snippet is not very readable (especially for someone who does not know the trick), but the list of paths is extremely clear (and also descriptive, due to the array having a meaningful name).

Note a `path/with spaces or so` needs to be quoted or escaped when you store it in an array. Example:

```
excludes=(
            a/b/c/d/e/f1
           'path/with spaces or so'
            another/path\ with\ spaces
         )
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blanks, don't add blanks or tabs to the end of each line
(except the blank after the back-slash),
and the same for the beginning of the continuation lines:

Like this :

```
./file-selector -exclude="a/b/c/d/e/f1,\
a/b/c/d/e/f2,\
a/b/c/d/e/f3,\
a/b/c/d/e/f4,\
a/b/c/d/e/f5,\
a/b/c/d/e/f6"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I went with the other answer because my script has some indentation and this makes it so I have to remove it just for those lines.